# How to use jira rest api to get all open and closed issues count for a specific user

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

I need to get count of all issues assigned to a user with status by using jira rest API.

```
      Open issues : 10
      In Progress : 5
      Closed : 30
```

I tried but was not able to get that information.Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use the JQL searching REST endpoint `rest/api/2/search?jql` for this. The downside is you have to do this separately for each status and we will rely on the `total` count returned by REST.

An example to search for assignee with the username **user** and issue in status **Open issues**:
`rest/api/2/search?jql=assignee=user+and+status="Open%20Issues"` will return the results will all information (issue fields etc).

Use `&maxResults=0` to get just the metadata only, `total` is found here. If we do`rest/api/2/search?jql=assignee=user+and+status="Open%20Issues&maxResults=0`, it will return something like:

```
{"startAt":0,"maxResults":0,"total":2,"issues":[]}
```

Comment: `curl -D- \
  -u user:token \
  -X GET \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  https://company.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/search?jql=status%20=%20Open%20AND%20resolution%20=%20Unresolved%20AND%20assignee%20in%20(currentUser())%20order%20by%20updated%20DESC&maxResults=0`     i am seeing following issue with above command `-sh: syntax error near unexpected token `('
`

Comment: I'm not familiar with Cloud instances. Anyway, try to add double quotes to the URL, the token error is quite apparent that it's detecting the bracket ( as a command or input.

Answer (score 0):

With JIRA search rest, you may need to call the JQLs separately to get the count for each status, but you can make use of gadget rest end to get what you are looking for, for eg

```
https://jira.com/rest/gadget/1.0/twodimensionalfilterstats/generate?filterId=filter-1&xstattype=statuses
```

Read more about this [here](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/fisheye-crucible/gadget/)